# Get datetime mask for a given locale

Tags: python, django, datetime, localization

How can I obtain the datetime mask (a string like "`dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm:ss`") for the locale that is currently used in my django application? 
(I need it in order to configure a javascript component which require a datetime mask as parameter and since I have a multilanguage site I can't hardcode that mask)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`django.utils.formats` module](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/formats.py):

```
from django.utils import formats
date_format = get_format('DATE_FORMAT')
```

`get_format(format_type, lang=None, use_l10n=None)` returns the current format used; set `use_l10n` to force localisation to be applied (defaults to your `settings.USE_L10N` flag), or use the `lang` argument to pick a specific language:

```
>>> from django.utils import formats
>>> formats.get_format('DATE_FORMAT')
'N j, Y'
>>> formats.get_format('DATE_FORMAT', lang='de')
'j. F Y'
```

See the [available date format strings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatefilter-date) to see what the various strings mean.

Alternatively, use the [javascript catalog view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/i18n/translation/#module-django.views.i18n), which includes JavaScript `get_format()` function.

Either way, the Django format is not a JS-recognized format. You have two options:

- Use [this Django snippet](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/84/) to add a `. strfdate()` method to the JavaScript `Date` prototype that recognises Django formats, or
- Install the [django-missing library](http://django-missing.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) which includes an updated version of the above snippet as a ready-to-include JS library.

If you need a JS-compatible mask, you'll need to do the translation yourself, based on those two `.strfdate()` examples.

Comment: ok... in my case a need a datetime, so formats.get_format('DATETIME_FORMAT')... which returns 'N j, Y, P'... how can I turn this string into a "normal" datetime mask?

Comment: Alternatively, use the [`django-missing` library](http://django-missing.readthedocs.org/en/latest/javascript.html#datetime-formatting) which adds date formatting for JavaScript; it includes an updated version of that snippet.

Comment: If your JS requires an actual format string of its own, rather than formatted date strings, I suspect you'll have to write your own converter to map the Django format strings into whatever format you need.

Comment: Yes Peter, that's the real problem... I don't need a string representation of a date, I need instead a string MASK containing literally something like "dd/mm/yyy HH:mm" (based on the language used by the user)